# PHP - How to check users level into a login session

Tags: php

I am using this code to protect my pages using login session:

```
    <?php
//PUT THIS HEADER ON TOP OF EACH UNIQUE PAGE
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    return header("location:login/main_login.php");

}
?>
```

but I'd like to check the users level, because I'd like to show e.g. page-one.php for users level 1 and 2; page-two.php for users level 3 and so on...

I tried in this way but it's not working:

```
     <?php
    session_start();
$level = 2;  
$_SESSION['level'] = $level;  
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        if($_SESSION['level'] == '0' && $_SESSION['level'] == '1') {
            return header("location: page-one.php");
        } else if ($_SESSION['level'] == '2') {
                    return header("location: page-two.php");

        }
    }
```

Any advice, please?

**EDIT** I edited my code, I found another solution: I stored level in a variable and I checked it together the username

Comment: I really don't know how to store level value in session. Is there another solution?

Comment: `return header(` this is pointless. `header()` returns nothing, (void)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will *always* be `false`:

```
if($_SESSION['level'] == '0' && $_SESSION['level'] == '1')
```

The same variable can't equal two different values *at the same time*.  Did you mean to use the comparison "or" operator (`||`) instead?:

```
if($_SESSION['level'] == '0' || $_SESSION['level'] == '1')
```

Or perhaps more else-if chaining?:

```
if($_SESSION['level'] == '0') {
  //...
} else if ($_SESSION['level'] == '1') {
  //...
} else if ($_SESSION['level'] == '2') {
  //...
}
```

Comment: @James69: Be more specific about your debugging, what you expect to happen, why you expect it to happen, etc.  Do you even *store* anything in `$_SESSION['level']` in the first place?  Where do you do that?  When you debug, how specifically does it fail?  What is the value in `$_SESSION['level']`?  What do you expect it to be?  Why?

Comment: So, every user has a level in my mysql database, but I don't know how I can recall level variable when a user's logged in. I'd like to show some pages for some users

Comment: @James69: Well, that's good and all, but regarding the specific question you're asking... What specifically is failing?  Take a look at your code.  You are reading a value in the session variable `$_SESSION['level']`.  Where did you store a value in that session variable?  What value did you store there?

Comment: "Its a lost cause, Dave."

Comment: @IncredibleHat Do you think it? I understood and I fixed it and now it's working ;) in few minutes I will edit my post with the solution

Comment: @David Thanks David, I understood what did you mean